# u-boot command description: mtdargs and boardsetup

Tags: u-boot

Reading  the [readme.Falcon](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/maz/u-boot/+/wip/psci/doc/README.falcon)  I found the following lines:

```
uboot> run mtdargs addip2 addtty
```

another command that is not working and I dont what it does is:   `fdt boardsetup`

When I treid to run this on my zynq board, it gives error.

Can someone tell me what this command does and how to enable it for zynq boards?